# Modifying template links on a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization

My wordpress site has English comment links (as shown below) that I want to translate.  For instance, instead of "5 Comments", I want it to display "5 Comentarii" and instead of "Leave a Comment", "Lasa comentariu".

How can I add these translations?

[image: Example in English]

Comment: Improving grammar, changing title to more closely match question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments may be featured on the single post view or in a popup window. The overall styles for the two sets of comments remain basically the same. The two template files are `comments.php` and `comments-popup.php` So find the file and edit. Than edit the front-end file also. it is always on the theme folder

Comment: there is the problem, there is nothing in those files!

Comment: <?php

// =============================================================================
// COMMENTS.PHP
// inside the "framework" subdirectory. Once inside, find your Stack's folder
// and look for a file called "wp-comments.php," where you'll be able to find
// the appropriate output.


?>

<?php x_get_view( x_get_stack(), 'wp', 'comments' ); ?>

Comment: Search into your theme files too because could be customized by the theme maker.

Comment: I found the wp-comments.php , but that file makes changes only inside of an article. I want to make the changes on the main page too!

Comment: You mean in front end ? Thats why i told you to search in theme's folder for any file with comments because there are everything that user sees.

Comment: here it's about php files. site is : shop.gabimolocea.com

Comment: I know what you mean but i cant see php files just from the link with inspector because they are server side.

Comment: I didn't found the line, I looked into all files with sublime and nothing. not in php files , not in .css too

Comment: If you can provide me an ftp access i would find it but these way i cant. But im sure it is on comments.php. Try it with finder the words Leave a comment.

Comment: yes, now i found it on /public_html/shop/wp-content/themes/x/framework/functions/renew.php ; That's why i hate custom themes:) thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use Loco Translate, best I've ever had, you can translate everything you want.